# prevent Empty Alert in reporting services

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am using report services to send an alert to users daily;
my data source is an oracle DB.
I want to send the alert, when my SELECT returns some records and don't want to send empty table to my users;
if you want more info, just let me know
thank you

Answer (score 0):

do attempt to hide the table function that returns true / false.

- example

if you do not return any data then hide a table that shows the data and show a text field containing "no corresponding data for the selected parameters"

in the "Visibility" put Hidden "expression":

= iif(count(Fields!FieldName.Value, "DataSetName") = 0, False, True)